# Why does an Arraylist doesn't accept it's own methods?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, methods

I have a program in which I want to print the average of the subjects of each student in a school.

The input is supposed to look something like this

```
000555 maths 88.7 physics 55.6 end
```

"End" is a keyword that shows that the input data of a student is terminated. The program is terminated whenever someone types stop.

I store all of the grades that come with the user input in an ArrayList. However, when I run the program I get the following error messages:

```
error: no suitable method found for add(String) (grades.add(str))
method Collection.add(Float) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to float)
error: no suitable method found for set(String) (grades.set(str))
etc...
```

I am aware of the fact that I cannot convert directly a String to a Float but I tried everything and it still doesn't work. What should I do in order for the compiler to accept these methods?

My code is the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Student
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String currentAnswer = "";
        String userWords = "";
        ArrayList<Float> grades = new ArrayList<Float>();

        System.out.println("Enter your a.m. as well as the subjects which you sat in finals");

            while(!currentAnswer.equals("end"))
            {
                currentAnswer = s.nextLine(); // reads the number or word
                userWords += "\n" + currentAnswer ;
                if(currentAnswer.equals("000000"))
                {
                    System.out.println("The sequence of numbers you entered is: "+userWords);
                    System.out.println("Exiting...");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                String[] wordsplit = currentAnswer.split(" ");
                String pattern = "^\\d+$";
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

                stud.clear();
                grades.clear();

                for (String str : wordsplit)
                {
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
                    if(str.matches("^\\d+$")){
                        String name = new String(str);
                    System.out.println("Code is: "+str);}
                    if(m.find()){
                    grades.add(str);
                    System.out.println("The numbers are: "+str);}   

                }

                grades.set(0,0);
                float sum = 0;
                for( float i : grades)
                {
                    sum+= i;
                }
                float avg = sum / grades.size();
                System.out.println("The average of student "+name+" is "+avg);

            } //while
    }//main
}//class
```

Comment: `grades` is a `ArrayList<Float>`.  Why do you think you should be able to add a `String` to it?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I made sure to cut the number parts out of the string

Comment: Use `grades.add(Float.parseFloat(str))`. The function, `Float.parseFloat` will parse `str` into a `float` provided `str` represents a number.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add String to your arrayList that is of Float type

```
if(m.find()){
     grades.add(str);    //str needs to be of float type
```